# Delay when using scroll snap

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use scroll snap to scroll between each section and fit the section to the view. However there is some sort of delay when I scroll and when the section snaps. It is weird because if I put the exact same code into a codepen(or the code snippet below) that delay will not happen. To try be more specific when I use codepen each step of my scroll wheel will scroll to a new section. However when I don't use codepen and just run my html file the scroll snap only happens when I stop scrolling or if I scroll one step down or up it will snap but only after what feels like a 750ms delay. Any help would be much appreciated.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
}


/* All the snapping stuff */

.scroll-container {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overscroll-behavior: contain;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
}


/* Other styles */

section {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: darkorchid;
}

section:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: turquoise;
}

section:nth-child(3n) {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-container">
  <section>
    <h2>Section 1</h2>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Section 2</h2>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Section 3</h2>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Section 4</h2>
  </section>
</div>
```